# Making connection to database using JNDI, but not using any properties file

Tags: java, jndi

I am trying to connect to a databse server using JNDI apporach. But I dont want to use any jndi.properties file or any changes in my web.xml file for parameters.

I have a hashMap of properties to connect to database server and I want to do something like this

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
Hashtable<String, String> authEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "javax.sql.DataSource");
authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.corporate.test.com:9822:mydb");
authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpass");
ctx = new InitialContext(authEnv);
ctx.bind("myjndi", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.corporate.test.com:9822:mydb");
System.out.println("Context is " + ctx);
ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("myjndi");
```

But my context is not getting initialized. and thats why i am not getting any datasource object.
I have created a object "myjndi" and tried to bidn my context with it. But its not working.
Please help me to figure me out that how can i do this kind of connection to database.

Comment: 'Not getting initialized' is not a problem description. What exactly is your objection to putting things into property files or web.xml like everybody else?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely wrong from start to finish.

- `javax.sql.DataSource` can't be used as a JNDI initial context factory
- "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz.corporate.test.com:9822:mydb" is not a JNDI provider URL
- putting a database URL into JNDI is pretty odd as well.

You can't just make it up as you go along. You should just use the JDBC API, or the container's `java:` namespace in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It means in such cases we should only go for JDBC APIS and JNDI connection will not work. Will JNDI always require a properties file? If so then cant we make connection to database using JNDI APIs by giving our HashMap of properties and the binding the JNDI name to the context. The JNDI name will also be created programatically. If you find any code snippet for connecting to database without using any external properties file, can you please give it to me.

Comment: JNDI doesn't *require* a properties file, but it is poor practice to hard-code things like hostnames and passwords that should be in external configuration files. I can't make head or tail of what you're actually trying to accomplish here, or why.

Comment: Ok I will try to make clear to you,  I have a war file which i deployed and able to access the URL. Now this web product has the facilty to store some custom object in it which have xml format. We can access those objects using APIs of that web product's JAR. I want to store my JNDI properties in that custom object and want to read those from there and try to make connection to database using JNDI. Can you please let me know how can this be done?

Comment: Generally when we make connection using JNDI approach we have something like this  ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/lighthouseCDI");

Comment: Still meaningless. Your web product has the facility to store 'some custom object' in what? You insist on using this custom object plus JNDI for this why? The usual approach is to define a resource that is looked up in the container's JNDI directly via java:comp/env which yields a DataSource. No 'custom object' necessary. You can't just make up arbitrary code and expect it to work, or expect other people to fix it for you.

Comment: What to do with the storage location of custom object? If you dont have answer please dont extend coomunication. I have made many JNDI connection using regular approch. This time its a kind of POC for me to connect to database using jndi and the connection parameter from some external xml file. This i have done for LDAP and now trying for database. If you are unable to understand my question please increase your IQ , it seems your IQ is very poor.

Comment: Even if the custom object is in my pants pocket and I am able to access that using the JAVA Apis provided by my web project then there should be no objection that where the object is kept. My question is very simple I have a database server to which I want to connect using the connection parameters from external xml file and using JNDI approach. How can I do that. If you can help me then only reply.